# Why doesn't Sympy's row_del() method work (example from geeksforgeeeks website)?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, matrix, row, sympy

TL;DR There is an inconsistency when using Sympy's `[Matrix].row_del()` method and websites seem to be reporting its use wrongly.

Note from the following [link from the geeksforgeeks website](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-sympy-matrix-row_del-method/) for an example of deleting matrix rows using sympy:

```
from sympy import *
  
# use the row_del() method for matrix
gfg_val = Matrix([[1, 2], [2, 3], [23, 45]]).row_del(0)
  
print(gfg_val)
```

The geeksforgeeks website gives the expected but *false* output as:

```
" Matrix([[2, 3], [23, 45]]) "
```

**HOWEVER**, the *actual* output can be found by running the code and getting:

```
None
```

What is going on here? Is the sympy program not working? I doubt the geeksforgeeks website has forged the output.

Furthermore, I've sometimes gotten the `None` output in my code to when trying to do the `row_del()` operation... anyone have an idea of what's going on here? Example code below:

```
from sympy import Matrix
from sympy import *

A = Matrix([(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6)])
display(A)

A = A.row_del(0)
display(A)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The discrepancy is probably related to the SymPy version used by that website.

In SymPy there are two main matrix types:

- `ImmutableDenseMatrix`: as the name suggests, you cannot modify in place this matrix. Every time you perform a matrix modification, the operation will return a new matrix.
- `MutableDenseMatrix`: Every time you perform a modification, the matrix will be modified in-place. No new matrix is created... As of SymPy 1.11.1, `Matrix` is an alias of this type.

Based on your findings, it might be that some Sympy version ago, `Matrix` was an alias of `ImmutableDenseMatrix`.

Anyway, this is an example that clarifies the concept.

```py
A = Matrix([(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6)])
B = ImmutableDenseMatrix([(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6)])
display(A, B)

A.row_del(0)
B = B.row_del(0)
display(A, B)
```

Comment: I see, thanks, interesting how this method only seems to be applicable for the ```row_del``` function but not the ```row_insert``` function. Not sure why there's a discrepancy here?

Comment: I have no idea. We need some core SymPy developer to answer this second question. :)

Comment: `MutableMatrix.row_insert` should not return the modified matrix. It is a [known issue](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/6992).